# jQuery missing target for Ajax on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to get a new comment form to load under a post. I have multiple posts on the page so I dynamically create the id's for each post using its primary id. I then pass that id to my script and I can see in the browser that both the html and the script are being rendered with the correct post id's but for some reason my new comment partial is not being rendered.

I'm using jQuery Mobile so I tried targeting the page-content div and it gets rendered fine but it won't render at all when I just try targeting the div that contains my post. Its as if the id doesn't exist but I can see it when I view source. Is there an issue with targeting dynamically created id's or is there some kind of trick to it?

Here is my javascript:

```
$("#post_<%= escape_javascript(@post.id.to_s) %>").append("<%= escape_javascript(render "comments/new", item: :post) %>");
```

My action:

```
def load_new_comment_partial
  @comment = Comment.new
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render "comments/new" }
  end
end
```

Comment: I can see in webbrick that the partial is getting rendered successfully, its just not showing on the page.

Answer (score 2):

This js code is tricky sometimes, you can try this:

```
$('<%= "#post_#{@post.id.to_s}" %>').append('<%= escape_javascript(render "comments/new", item: @post) %>');
```

That code above should be on load_new_comment_partial.js.erb

I've changed the quotation and also the item param I've changed to @post instead of :post

And in your action you can replace

```
format.js { render "comments/new" }
```

with

```
format.js
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The :post symbol in my JS is actually being passed to meet an if condition, not really as a variable (forgot to mention that) but I tried changing to just format.js and made sure the controller action name matched the JS file to avail. Do you think there's a problem with the first part of my JS? I can successfully target any other elements on my page.